# Dll execute during MSI execution(Installer)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, dllimport, orca

I created an MSI for my application and i want my dll to execute during installation of this MSI.
How can i add my dll to MSI. I read something on ORCA but getting error.

Can anyone help to add my dll to msi using orca.
My dll contain a message box and registry entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to use Orca directly for creating installer. Try to use [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) instead. There are documentation, tutorials, etc. on WiX. You will find information on creating custom dll to.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Orca. Just follow the following tutorial:  http://www.codeproject.com/kb/install/msicustomaction.aspx
It was simple to implement for someone who doesn't know WIX and doesn't have the time to learn it.

My only problem now is that I can't get the custom action to run when the MSI is executed silently. See:
[Windows Installer custom action BEFORE any validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721093/windows-installer-custom-action-before-any-validation)